# Question regarding number of polynomials over $\mathbb F_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

I have a question regarding polynomials over $\mathbb F_3$ ($\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$).
In a homework problem we have to check how many third degree polynomials there are over $\mathbb F_3$.

The question is whether there are exactly $54$ or not. I'm confused as to how to go about this.
I can see how there should be a finite number of possibilities, but I don't know how to prove that there is a certain number of them.

Comment: Did it ask about the number of _polynomials_ or _polynomial functions_? The first is much easier; there are obviously exactly $3^4$ third-degree polynomials.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $3^4$ polynomials with degree **at most** $3$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oops. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich As for polynomial functions: if you are referring to polynomial functions over $\Bbb F_3$, then by linear interpolation it's easy to see that *every* function over $\Bbb F_3$ is represented by a polynomial of degree $2$. However, it is more common in abstract algebra to define polynomials "formally" (i.e. as an expression with an "indeterminate" variable)

Comment: Oops, I was counting polynomials as though the leading coefficient could vanish. In fact there are $2(3^3)=54$ polynomials of degree $3$.

Comment: @Sokra Have you taken a course in probability or discrete mathematics? If the question were to count the number of tuples $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$ for which $a_i \in \{0,1,2\}$ for all $i$ and $a_3 \neq 0$, would you be able to come up with an answer?

Comment: The question was about polynomials, not polynomial functions. Unfortunately, I haven't taken probability or anything yet, the question was a homework problem for my linear algebra class. I just can't seem to figure out how to come up with 2(3^3) polynomials of degree 3.

Comment: Ah I think I might have understood how to get there, after looking up some probability stuff, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$a x^3+b x^2+c x+d$$
Modulus $3$ coefficient $a$ can be $1$ or $2$, while $b,c,d$ have a range $(0..3)$

Thus they are $2\times 3\times 3\times 3=54$